# Event handler doesn't change text in Label

Tags: c#, asp.net, event-handling

Problem: the event handler `quantity_TextChanged` does not change the session variable "list" to reflect the current state. The event handler is attached to all the textboxes generated by `addItemRowToTable`, and they're told apart by their assigned ids.

I'm definitely sure that something's missing, but I'm not sure.

Additional Info: I need this in a way that the changes made to multiple Textboxes are all saved into 1 Session variable for later use further in the session, in the order as they are presented in the table. The values from each of the Textboxes are then used in their Label that's beside it (1 Label per Textbox).

Desired result:

```
Header                      Header2 
[TextBox with value of 42]  [Label displaying 42]
[TextBox with value of 76]  [Label displaying 76]
[TextBox with value of 105] [Label displaying 105]
```

WebForm1.aspx.cs

```
protected void Page_LoadComplete(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (Session["list"] != null)
    {
        List<int> numbers = Session["list"] as List<int>;
        int index = 0;
        foreach (int item in numbers)
        {
            tblItems.Rows.AddAt(index + 1, addItemRowToTable(item, index));
            // For debugging purposes
            Response.Write("<script>console.log(\"" + item.ToString() + "\");</script>");
            index++;
        }
    }

}

private TableRow addItemRowToTable(int item, int index)
{
    TableCell[] cells = { new TableCell(), new TableCell() };
    TableRow row = new TableRow();

    TextBox box = new TextBox();
    box.ID = String.Format("{0}_q", index);
    box.Attributes["type"] = "number";
    box.Attributes["min"] = "1";
    box.Attributes["width"] = "60px";
    box.TextChanged += new EventHandler(quantity_TextChanged);
    box.AutoPostBack = true;
    cells[0].Controls.Add(box);

    Label lbl = new Label();
    lbl.ID = String.Format("{0}_l", index);
    lbl.Text = item.ToString();
    cells[1].Controls.Add(lbl);

    foreach (TableCell cell in cells)
        row.Cells.Add(cell);
    return row;
}

protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (Session["list"] != null)
    {
        List<int> numbers = Session["list"] as List<int>;
        numbers.Add(0);
        Session["list"] = numbers;
    }
    else
    {
        List<int> numbers = new List<int>();
        numbers.Add(0);
        Session["list"] = numbers;
    }
}

private void quantity_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (Session["list"] != null)
    {
        TextBox item = sender as TextBox;
        int position = Convert.ToInt32(item.ID.Split('_')[0]);

        List<int> numbers = Session["list"] as List<int>;
        numbers[position] = Convert.ToInt32(item.Text);
        Session["list"] = numbers;
    }
}
```

WebForm1.aspx

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="WebForm1.aspx.cs" Inherits="Assignment2.WebForm1" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div>
        <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" OnClick="Button1_Click" />
        <br />
        <br />
        <asp:Table ID="tblItems" runat="server">
            <asp:TableHeaderRow>
                <asp:TableHeaderCell>Header</asp:TableHeaderCell>
                <asp:TableHeaderCell>Header2</asp:TableHeaderCell>
            </asp:TableHeaderRow>
        </asp:Table>
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your expectation is that you should start seeing label text change as soon as you type in the textbox?

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya Yes; When the changes are made to a Textbox, AutoPostback must fire & the Label beside it has to update to the changed value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you don't need to be in `Page_LoadComplete`. It is probably your attempt to add the correct amount of textboxes after a button click I think. But the button click should just add a new TextBox, nothing more. In Page_Load you need to add the TextBoxes that are stored in the Session.
See the below sample for a working solution with an TextChanged event that works because all the correct controls are recreated on postback.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (IsPostBack == false)
    {
        //do not add or manipulate dynamic controls inside an ispostback check
    }

    //check if the session exists
    if (Session["list"] != null)
    {
        //add the correct number of textboxes from session
        for (int i = 1; i <= Convert.ToInt32(Session["list"]); i++)
        {
            addTextBox(i);
        }
    }
}


private void addTextBox(int index)
{
    //create a new textbox
    TextBox tb = new TextBox();
    tb.ID = "DynamicTextBox" + index;
    tb.AutoPostBack = true;

    //add an event to the textbox
    tb.TextChanged += new EventHandler(quantity_TextChanged);

    //add the textbox to the page
    PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(tb);
}


protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int index = 1;

    //get the current textbox count if it exists
    if (Session["list"] != null)
    {
        index = Convert.ToInt32(Session["list"]) + 1;
    }

    //add a new textbox
    addTextBox(index);

    //upate the session with the new value
    Session["list"] = index;
}


private void quantity_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //display the textbox value in a label for testing
    Label1.Text = ((TextBox)sender).Text;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answering, but i want to keep the values of the Textboxes added to the table, and then render the values onto the Labels. I also want the Textboxes and Lables to appear inside the table. For this to work, I need to store the changes made to the Textboxes into 1 Session variable.

Comment: Those things have no relation to each other. In order to save the correct textbox values or show the correct labels you will first need to have working code for adding textboxes dynamically. If not then you won't even be able to get the values since they will be lost if the textboxes are not recreated.

Comment: The textboxes were already capable of being added correctly; It's just that they can't store their values into the Session variable.

Comment: No they were not. If you do not add them correctly you cannot get the values after a PostBack, But now you can use FindControl since you know the ID sequence and get the values.

Comment: Ok...After performing a major refactor for the actual form (not the one above), I'll admit that your solution works. Thanks for your help. :)